# MATLAB matrix coefficients how to get them

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi i have to resolve AX=0 in matlab. The problem is that I don't have the A coefficients I need to extract them from q(x)f(x) - q(x) = 0, a complex expression. In this system the variables are a0 a1 a2 b0 b1 b2, since I going to evaluate the expression for a given set of points x, p(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 and q(x) = b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2 and f(x) is some function. So i got a system of 6 variables and the number of equation is the quantity of points. My question is how i extract the coefficients of the A matrix including the 0 for any variable? I have been trying several ways but nothing. Do I have to manually copy the variables coefficients for all the given points (x, f(x))? Please i like the thing well done help me in case there is a solution even if it is big. just guide me.

Comment: This question is very difficult to read. What does "extract coefficients" mean? Are you looking to *find* appropriate coefficients? What technique are you using? What have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess you want to solve q(x)f(x) - p(x) = 0 (where q,p is quadric and f arbitary function, respect to x), not AX=0. Note: AX=0 is linear equation while q(x)f(x) - p(x) = 0  not necessarily. If so, it may be impossible to "extract coefficients" and what you need is nonlinear equation solver, check out: fsolve function.